# test exec.Cmd running sudo

Tags: go

How do you test sudo in test?

I have a function:

```
func SudoF(){
    str, _ := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "sudo ls .").Output()
    fmt.Println(string(str))
}

func TestSudoF(t *testing.T) {
    // Maybe som setup here?
    SudoF()
}
```

I would like to read the outcome to verify the test, rather than mocking - if possible?

As you can see this test will not work, as it will hang, waiting for typing in the password for sudo.

I would like to be able to run the test - if possible, maybe with som test setup?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: If you want to use sudo like this, you must either configure it to not request a password, or supply one via stdin, regardless of the language you are using.

Comment: How would you supply the password via stdin?

Comment: visudo and alter the user or group that your test runs as to ``ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL``

Comment: `sudo` is difficult to pass script a password with by design, but does have some options: https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line